# Can I do the following when solving my integration??

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation, improper-integrals, products

I appreciate any feedback for my question.

I have an integration as follows

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi} \prod_i \frac{1}{1+ x_ig(\theta)} d\theta $$

I have that $g(\theta)$ is the defined as piecewise

$$ g(\theta) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         1 & \mbox{if $\theta_{min} \leq \theta\leq \theta_{max}$};\\
        0 & \mbox{if $OW$}.\end{array} \right. $$

Can I do the following to solve my integration?
$$\int_{\theta_{min}}^{\theta_{max}}\frac{1}{2\pi} \prod_i \frac{1}{1+ x_i 1} d\theta $$
$$=\frac{(\theta_{max}-\theta_{min})}{2\pi} \prod_i \frac{1}{1+ x_i 1} $$

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, but you also need to include the part ($[-\pi,\theta_{\rm min}]$ plus $[\theta_{\rm max},\pi]$) where $g(\theta)=0$, note that $1/(1+x_ig(\theta)) = 1 \not= 0$ in this case. This gives an additional contribution $\frac{(\pi-\theta_{\rm max})}{2\pi} + \frac{(\theta_{\rm min}+\pi)}{2\pi} = 1  - \frac{\theta_{\rm max}-\theta_{\rm min}}{2\pi}$

Comment: thank you very much ! you are right I dont know why I missed it. Appreciate it

Comment: @Tyrone You may want to consider the importance of $1/(2\pi i)$